# Workflow does not start automatically on item update when powershell script triggered by task scheduler

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

On SharePoint 2010, I created a powershell script that update some listitems. A workflow automatically start on item update.
Mys script works fine when launched in my session.

I created a new task to launch my script every hour. And then, the workflow does not start after item update.

The user used to execute the task has these rights :
- Local admin on the server
- member of WSS_ADMIN_WPG group
- Sharepoint owner on the root web
- member of SPShellAdmin (Get-SPShellAdmin)

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[System accounts will not trigger automatic workflows](http://blogs.technet.com/b/victorbutuza/archive/2009/03/14/workflows-do-not-start.aspx?Redirected=true). Ideally you should use another account to run your script, but if not you could add `$SPSite.get_WorkflowManager().StartWorkflow($item, $association, $eventData)` [ref 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.workflowmanager.aspx) [ref 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms435535) to your powershell script to manually initiate the workflow.